# How to filter one dataframe with the nearest time to another?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

For this project, I have two dataframes one called **df1** and another called **df2**. These dataframes are not the same size (don't think that matters).

Each of them have a ***datetime*** in the first column. What I am trying to do is:

I want to make a new dataframe **df3** that contains the remaining data from the **df2** but only for the when the original times in the first column are closest to the **df1**.

Here is an example of what the dataframes might look like:

```
 print (df1)
 Output:
                 Date       Val
 0 2015-02-24 00:00:02  1.764052
 1 2015-02-24 00:01:15  0.400157
 2 2015-02-24 00:02:22  0.978738
 3 2015-02-24 00:03:39  2.240893
 4 2015-02-24 00:04:00  1.867558

 print (df2)
 Output:
                 Date       Val      Name  
 0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  -0.977278    John
 1 2015-02-24 00:01:00   0.950088    Robert
 2 2015-02-24 00:02:00  -0.103219    Sam
 3 2015-02-24 00:03:00   0.151357    Tim
 4 2015-02-24 00:04:00   0.410599    Hector 
 5 2015-02-24 00:05:00   0.673247    Melissa
```

Then what I want to be able to retrieve is something like this:

```
print (df2)
 Output:
                 Date       Val      Name  
 0 2015-02-24 00:00:00  -0.977278    John
 1 2015-02-24 00:01:00   0.950088    Robert
 2 2015-02-24 00:02:00  -0.103219    Sam
 3 2015-02-24 00:04:00   0.410599    Hector
 4 2015-02-24 00:04:00   0.410599    Hector 
 5 2015-02-24 00:05:00   0.673247    Melissa
```

I have searched around a bit and found that there were two similar posts on here [example-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63202666/how-to-grab-a-row-with-nearest-timestamp-in-a-pandas-dataframe) [example-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42264848/pandas-dataframe-how-to-query-the-closest-datetime-index), but the difference being they just want a single value returned or a single row. For my purposes I want it to be 'Filtered' so to speak.

If anyone can provide any insight, that would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, I believe this gives you what you're looking for.

```
df1['df2_idx'] = df1.Date.apply(lambda x: [(abs(df2['Date'] - x)).idxmin()][0])
df3 = df2.reindex(df1['df2_idx'], axis=0).reset_index().drop(['df2_idx'], axis=1)
```

The first line just finds the row in `df2` that is closest to each row in `df1` and appends the indices as a column to `df1` like this:

```
                 Date       Val  df2_idx
0 2015-02-24 00:00:02  1.764052        0
1 2015-02-24 00:01:15  0.400157        1
2 2015-02-24 00:02:22  0.978738        2
3 2015-02-24 00:03:39  2.240893        4
4 2015-02-24 00:04:00  1.867558        4
```

The second row then just subsets `df2` with the column of indices.  The final output is

```
                 Date       Val    Name
0 2015-02-24 00:00:00 -0.977278    John
1 2015-02-24 00:01:00  0.950088  Robert
2 2015-02-24 00:02:00 -0.103219     Sam
3 2015-02-24 00:04:00  0.410599  Hector
4 2015-02-24 00:04:00  0.410599  Hector
```